# $\operatorname{tr}(A^\text{T}A) = \operatorname{tr}(A)$ if $A$ is idempotent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

I know that $
\operatorname{tr}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(A)$ if $A$ is idempotent. Now I need to calculate $\operatorname{tr}(A^\text{T}A)$. I have done some simulation which shows $\operatorname{tr}(A^\text{T}A)=\operatorname{tr}(A)$ but I don’t know how to prove it.

Sorry if I’m making a wrong claim.

Comment: How much simulation did you do? It is easy to construct a $2\times 2$ counterexample.  In fact, most $2\times 2$ examples are counterexamples.  Just make sure that $A$ isn't symmetric.

Comment: This is true if $A$ is a self-adjoint idempotent but not in general. Of course in that case $A^T A = A^2 = A$ is clear.

Comment: Try $A=[0 \ 1 ; 0 \ 1]$.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't hold. Take eg. the matrix
$$A= \left[\begin{array}{cc} \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} \\ -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \end{array} \right].$$
We see that $\operatorname{tr} A = 1,$ but the trace of
$$A^TA = \left[\begin{array}{cc} \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} \\ -\frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \end{array} \right] \left[\begin{array}{cc} \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} \\ -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \end{array} \right] =\left[\begin{array}{cc} \frac{5}{9} & -\frac{5}{9} \\ -\frac{5}{9} & \frac{5}{9} \end{array} \right]$$
is $\frac{10}{9}.$

Answer (score 2):

Take a simple counterexample
$$A= \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array} \right]$$
$\operatorname{tr} A = 1,$
$$A^TA= \left[\begin{array}{cc} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right]$$

$\operatorname{tr} A^TA = 2$.